# c++ compiling errors void function

Tags: c++

When i try to compile these errors shows up

> line 5:   [Error] expected initializer before 'void'
>   line 27:  [Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token

help me i need to send it to my doctor by 3 hours

```c
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void ConvertToCelsuis (int temp)
void ConvertToFahernheit (int temp)

int main()
{
   char ch;
   int temp;

   cout<<"enter a temprature followed by a charcter"<<endl;
   cin>>temp>>ch>>endl;
   if (ch=='f'|ch=='F')
   ConvertToFahernheit (temp);

   else if (ch=='c'|ch=='C')
   ConvertToCelsuis (temp);
   Return 0;
}


void ConvertToFahernheit (int temp)
{
  float F;
}

{

   F=(temp*1.8)+32;
   cout<<F;
   cout<<endl;

}

void ConvertToCelsuis (int temp)
{
  float C;

  {

  C=((temp-32)*0.5);
  cout<<C;
  cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: you are missing semi-colons on both of those prototype lines.

Comment: and you're ending the `ConvertToFahernheit()` function early with that `}` after `float F`

Comment: @PaulRoub I think you mean when he closes scope with the curly braces right?

Comment: Yep. Edited the typo to confuse fewer people. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the `return` keyword may not be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

on these lines:

```
void ConvertToCelsuis (int temp)
void ConvertToFahernheit (int temp)
```

you are missing semicolons. After you fix this you will have to delve into other compilation problems, for eg:

```
cin>>temp>>ch>>endl;
```

That line is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon at the end of your declaration.

```
void ConvertToCelsuis (int temp);
void ConvertToFahernheit (int temp);
```